# PyGame: how do I make a sequence of colors?

Tags: python, pygame

How can I write a code where I can make my game transition through these colors once per second every 30 frames?

```
self.bg_color = 0, 0, 0
self.bg_color = 255, 0, 0
self.bg_color = 0, 255, 0
self.bg_color = 0, 0, 255
self.bg_color = 255, 165, 0
self.bg_color = 255, 255, 0
self.bg_color = 199, 97, 20
```

EDIT:

would it help if I showed the skeleton?

```
from __future__ import division
import math
import sys
import pygame


class MyGame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
        pygame.init()

        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))

            self.bg_color = 0, 0, 0

        self.FPS = 30
        self.REFRESH = pygame.USEREVENT+1
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.REFRESH, 1000//self.FPS)


    def run(self):
        running = True
        while running:
            event = pygame.event.wait()

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            elif event.type == self.REFRESH:
                self.draw()

            else:
                pass

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)

        pygame.display.flip()


MyGame().run()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

I've been looking around for a way to do it and so far no luck, that's why I asked here

Comment: i just have the basic skeleton for the game and to be honest i have no idea

Comment: ah, ok. You'll find you'll have more luck with help if you have something already started,and come for help when you are stuck. For two reasons, it shows effort to solve your problem, and also provides a specific way to help.

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving me much to go on here, but I'll give it a try.

Make an int called framesSinceColourSwitch, an array that you store all your colours in called backgroundColours, and an int called currentColourIndex.

Somewhere in your code you're refreshing your frame, repaint, redraw, something like that. Add one to framesSinceColourSwitch when you repaint. Write an if statement that checks when it gets to 30.

Inside that, you change the background colour to the colour in backgroundColours at currentColourIndex. You'll also want to set your framesSinceColourSwitch to 0 again and add one to currentColourIndex. Last thing you'll want to do is mod currentColourIndex by the number of colours in your background array.

I'm leaving all the details to you, because I'm guessing you're still learning and I don't want to slow you down. Also I don't have your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import division
import math
import sys
import pygame


class MyGame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.listofcolors = [[0, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0],
                            [0, 0, 255], [255, 165, 0], [255, 255, 0],
                            [199, 97, 20]]
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
        pygame.init()

        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))

        self.bg_color = self.listofcolors[0]

        self.FPS = 30
        self.REFRESH = pygame.USEREVENT+1
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.REFRESH, 1000//self.FPS)


    def run(self):
        timer_cap = 30     # Frequenzy to change the background color
        cur_timer = 0      # Current timer to check against the timer_cap
        current_color = 0  # Current color index
        running = True
        while running:
            event = pygame.event.wait()

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            elif event.type == self.REFRESH:
                self.draw()

            else:
                pass

            # Here we control the background color
            if cur_timer == timer_cap:
                cur_timer = 0
                if current_color == len(self.listofcolors)-1:
                    current_color = 0
                else:
                    current_color += 1
                self.bg_color = self.listofcolors[current_color] 
            else:
                cur_timer += 1

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)

        pygame.display.flip()


MyGame().run()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```